# how can i send data from whmcs hook to admin module files?

Tags: php, whmcs

i created an **addon moodule in WHMCS** and its working just fine!
now im trying to work and learn hooks

i have tried somethings for client side and it worked but i have problem in admin side

here is what i tried so far in **hooks.php** on my **module directory**:

```
add_hook('AdminAreaPage', 1, function($vars) {

$extraVariables = [];
if ($vars['filename'] == 'addonmodules') {
    
    $extraVariables['newVariable1'] = $vars['admin_username'];
}

return $extraVariables;
});
```

but when i in list.php (a file in module directory) want to get the $extraVariables like below, its null !

```
<?php var_dump($extraVariables); ?>
```

what im doing wrong or whats im missing?
i simply just want to get data im creating in hook in my module files

**does whmcs hook variables only works and have access in tpl files?**

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/admin-area/#adminareapage), the answer is, yes variables are only available inside the template(s)

> **Response**
> Accepts a return of key/value pairs to be **made available to the template layer as additional template variables**.

Comment: i created a tpl file with $smarty and when i pass data with: $smarty->assign('myvar', 'World'); in myModule.php, it successfully shows data in tpl file but again i cannot access data that im sending from my hook that i put in question